# Syntax error on join sub-select

Tags: ms-access, join, db2, ms-access-2007, subquery

I have 4 fields that I need ->

1. USERID
2. LOCATION
3. REPORT_MGR_USERID (reporting manager user ID)
4. Manager Location (this is not actually stored)

To get the 4th one, I need to build it using SQL. I can do this via the "USERID" and "LOCATION" fields.

Here is my attempt. I am running a query within Access 2007, via a linked DB2 table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT employee_table.LOCATION, employee_table.USERID, employee_table.REPORT_MGR_USERID,  manager_location 
FROM employee_table main
JOIN  employee_table (SELECT DISTINCT employee_table.LOCATION FROM employee_table AS sub WHERE sub.USERID = main.REPORT_MGR_USERID) manager_location
```

When I run it, it's giving me this error ->

```
Syntax error in FROM clause
```

and then highlights the JOIN keyword.

This looks correct from everything I've looked at....

EDIT:

Thanks to David W, this is the working version for future reference ->

```
SELECT DISTINCT main.LOCATION, main.USERID, main.REPORT_MGR_USERID,  manager_data.LOCATION 
FROM employee_table main
INNER JOIN employee_table manager_data
ON main.REPORT_MGR_USERID=manager_data.USERID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying both a table name `employee_table` and a subselect `(SELECT DISTINCT....)` in the first JOIN clause. And there's no ON condition, although that may be what you want?

The specification of `employee_table` in that JOIN might just be a typo, since you've provided an alias for the subselect...

**Edit** The light bulb just went on and I understand what the OP wants. Here we go:

```
SELECT DISTINCT main.LOCATION, main.USERID, main.REPORT_MGR_USERID, manager_data.manager_location 
   FROM employee_table main
   INNER JOIN employee_table manager_data
     on main.REPORT_MGR_USERID=manager_data.USERID
```

Comment: Correct. We don't have a 'manager_location' field, but I can build it by using the "manager_id" field, and getting the "location field" for that. This is a self-join.

Comment: In looking more at your query, it looks a little peculiar. You say you have no location field, but you're selecting ADVHRVP_ENT_EMPLOYEE_LIST.LOCATION from that table? Looks like that's a qualified reference to a different table?

Comment: @hacket I think there's some table information missing here. If the field you need isn't present in the table, but is coming from ADVHRVP_ENT_EMPLOYEE_LIST, you can join as I've tried to infer in the modified answer above. As I said, the query you've posted looks a little confused to me, so I tried to sort it out as best I could infer.

Comment: AHA! I think I finally see what you're wanting. Check the answer now.

Comment: I am selecting all the data from the same table. I just substituted the name 'employee_table' for 'ADVHRVP_ENT_EMPLOYEE_LIST', which are one and the same. I did this to make it easier to read.

Comment: Okay. Check the revised answer above. Pretty sure I've got it for you this time :)

Comment: this looks to have worked, but now it prompts me for input for each of my SELECT fields...?

Comment: ARRGH!!! I forgot to fix the table/field aliases. Sorry 'bout that! Fixed it @hacket

Comment: I admire your persistence, David.  :-)  +1

Comment: @HansUp LOL thanks, hey people have been patient/persistent w/me in the past, enjoy helping, too! :)

Comment: @DavidW You are awesome, this worked! I have posted the updated query that works as well.

Comment: Great! I'm glad I was able to give you a push in the right direction. Blessings!

Answer (score 1):

The Access db engine doesn't recognize `JOIN` as a synonym for `INNER JOIN`.  It throws a syntax error any time you use just `JOIN` alone.  Change it to `INNER JOIN`.

However, I suspect you may still have trouble after that correction.  The remainder of the join expression is confusing and I don't understand what it's intended to accomplish.  So after fixing the `JOIN` issue, you may still get another syntax error.

Comment: Take the SQL David W suggested and substitute INNER JOIN for JOIN.  Is that what you're after?

Comment: this seems to work but now prompts me for input for each of my SELECT fields...?